# Mystery Monochrome Monitor

Tags: vga, crt, restoration

I rescued an old monochrome monitor from the e-waste, but the cord had already been cut. So now I’m trying to see if I can get it working. I know…

This is of an era that rather than have a connectors to attach cords, it had a power and display cord coming out the back, now gone. So my first question is: Did this formerly have a VGA connector coming out the back?

Make: Relisys
Model: RM9501
Year: 1992

[image: CRT Label]

Here is the monitor cable:

[image: monitor cable]

And if it is helpful, here is the label on the tube:

[image: tube label]

Most of the pin outs I’ve seen for VGA suggest that there’s usually a green wire. The second dark wire is purple.

VGA? Or something else?

How would you suggest I rewire this guy?

Comment: Suggest you post this on the retro computing stack exchange. (And don't double post)

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat of a guess here, but I suspect the connections went to a 9-pin male D-sub connector, and the TTL-level pin functions were as follows:

Pin 1. Shield

Pin 2. GND  (black)

Pin 6. Intensity  (??)

Pin 7. Video (orange)

Pin 8. Horizontal Sync (+) 18.432 kHz (yellow)

Pin 9. Vertical Sync (-) 50Hz  350 lines (blue)

That leaves the violet wire which may be intensity or it may be another ground in this scenario. Or something else entirely.

Suggest you trace out the ground wires first. If I am correct this is a TTL monitor that is similar to the IBM 5151. Applying reverse polarity to the inputs could damage a TTL level input.

This is based on [this](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/5151/misc/5151_video_cable.htm) photo of an IBM 5151 cable:

[image]

Note that it specifically mentions that IBM did not maintain consistent colors in the cable (they 'varied').

And also [this](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/oa/OA%20-%20IBM%20Monochrome%20Display%20(5151).pdf) schematic of the IBM 5151 (again on the minuszerodegrees site)

[image]

And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter) pinout of the IBM Monochrome Display Adapter from Wikipedia.

[image]

Comment: Can I wire this to a 15-pin VGA connector?

Comment: The above answer is likely incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

A general search of the [FCC ID number](https://fccid.io/EWB) tells me that this unit was manufactured in 1990 by OEM Orion(as verified by your photo of the picture tube), but doesn't provide any other information.  Based upon the year of manufacture, which could be possibly verified by taking the monitor apart and looking for date codes on components, it is likely a VGA monochrome monitor.  The link above also shows an almost identical model number that does state that it is a VGA monitor.

If I were to try to use this monitor, I would definitely take it apart to test continuity with the wires in the cable, starting with testing continuity to find the ground wires.  Having found the grounds, the video signal wire should have a 75 ohm terminating resistance to ground, so that should be easy to identify.

The horizontal and vertical sync signals could likely be identified by tracing them through the circuitry to whatever interface IC they end up in, or simply by trying them with a live input signal...